# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler --- Execution Package

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have completed the JMeter WebDriver Groovy coding. Is it possible to execute this program scripts at other Windows PC without JMeter installed? Can you please advise the steps? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: What you want doesn't really make sense. WDS is Java software so JRE is a must to run, but JMeter is a Java app too, so if you _can_ run Java on a machine, you should just execute the jmx file via JMeter jar archive.

Comment: I assume you do know how to run a jmx file on the command line w/o the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

No.

In order to run a JMeter test you need a JMeter instance. So you will either need to copy your JMeter to the "other" machine(s) or consider alternative approaches which are in:

- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/)

both are capable of automaticallt downloading JMeter and JMeter Plugins of your choice, however you will need to either install Java and Maven or Java and Taurus first.